# How do I show/hide an <li> based on its text content using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I need to hide/show an `<li>` based on its text content. In the example below, I want to only show the list item that contains "content 1" and hide the rest of the list items. I'm sure there are several ways to do this. Would I need to convert the list to an array and then use the "includes" method, then append style display none/ display block using a conditional statement?

I would have several unordered lists on a page and therefore target them with the wrapper div's ID.

```
 <div id="myDiv">
    <ul class="myList">
        <li>content 1</li>   
        <li>content 2</li>  
        <li>content 3</li>   
        <li>content 4</li>     
     </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: You might want to use a framework/library like react or vue where such use cases are common and easy to handle

Comment: How is the choice of "content 1" determined? Is it constant?

Comment: See [Hide div that contains specific text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text).

Comment: Yes, the text content is constant. I want to learn to do this with Vanilla JS.

Comment: Maybe instead of hiding from text, hide by item number. Take a look at this library [show-more](https://github.com/tomik23/show-more)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in the subject you ask for a JavaScript solution, here is one. Iterate the `li` elements involved and set their `display` style depending on their text content:

```js
for (let li of document.querySelectorAll("#myDiv li")) {
    li.style.display = li.textContent === "content 1" ? "" : "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <ul class="myList">
    <li>content 1</li>
    <li>content 2</li>
    <li>content 3</li>
    <li>content 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is interesting shorthand. I see what's happening, but am a bit puzzled that this order of things works. That the style statement = the text Content, then the triple equals, then the conditional.

Comment: Operators have a priority: First equality (`===`), then ternary (`? :`), then assignment (`=`). And I skipped over the member access (`.`) operator, which really comes first.

Comment: I swapped out the triple equals for .includes. Does includes have the same  priority as triple equals? I'm still a bit confused on the order of things. Even with your explanation of priority - what's determining the order of things here, as it seems to be unintuitive when I try to square it with the priority. Apologies - I'm a total newb.

Comment: With `includes` it will work fine too. So the order (with `===`) is: `li.textContent === "content 1"`. Then the ternary operator is evaluated, so if the `===` expression evaluates to true, then it evaluates to `""`, else to `"none"`. Then the assignment of that string happens next, and so we get `li.style.display = "none"` (or `""`).

Comment: I guess what's throwing me is that the code is seemingly not written in the order of precedence.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to achieve the text of an element, then you should use
   [TextContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or [innerHtml](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML). *textContent* is more preferred
   because of some security issues and the latest syntax.
2. You can also use [indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) method to check if some string in
   the element exists or not. It is a string method. A similar syntax
   for this one is `Node.textContent.indexOf("word") != -1)`.
3. Don't forget that you have more than one li tag so you must check
   the value of them with a loop(for). Preferably [for let foo of
   bar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

```js
const li = document.querySelectorAll('li');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (let x of li) {
    if (x.textContent === 'content1') {
      x.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      x.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>content1</li>
  <li>content2</li>
  <li>content3</li>
</ul>

<button type="button">Hide</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.myList li')]
.forEach(li => li.style.display = li.innerText === 'content 1' ? 'block' : 'none');
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <ul class="myList">
    <li>content 1</li>
    <li>content 2</li>
    <li>content 3</li>
    <li>content 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Alternatively:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.myList li')]
.forEach(li => {
  'content 1' !== li.innerText && (li.style.display = 'none')
});
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <ul class="myList">
    <li>content 1</li>
    <li>content 2</li>
    <li>content 3</li>
    <li>content 4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```